# Fatal Error: fetch()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, fatal-error

I have the below snippet of code. When I run the whole program, it fails at this section with the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in <filename> on line 26`. I'm really not sure what I should do to fix the problem. If it matters, I ran the SQL query against my database and it returns exactly what it should.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email';
        $query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['email']);

        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        $row = $result->fetch();   //fails on this line

        if(empty($results)) {
            $passset = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While that link is helpful for debugging PDO, it's not at all a duplicate of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns TRUE or FALSE, not a result object.

Change this:

```
$row = $result->fetch();
```

To this:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Coming back to PHP after an 8-month hiatus; I was bound to screw up something simple. Thank you, I appreciate it!